# Can't modify the list of external accessories used in Info.plist Visual Studio 2013

Tags: xamarin

I need to include an external accessory protocol to my Info.plist as described [here.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1635#c1)

However, VS (2013) doesn't allow to modify this property. I also looked in XS on my mac and it looks like the UI changed since then.

Does anyone know how to add an external accessory protocol? It will be best if you can show how to add it using XML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

Turns out that they did change the menu and now (on XS.iOS) at the bottom there is a tab "Source".

[image]

If you add another entry (click Add new entry), then select "Supported external accessory protocols" from the drop down menu and add your protocol it should be all done.

In XMl it looks like:
`<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
  <array>
    <string>com.YOUR.PROTOCOL</string>
  </array>`

But I am not too sure if you can add it directly in VS...

Hope that helps

Comment: Note: You can add it directly in code (worked for me). Thank you!